# flutter: Is there a way to use the front camera?

Tags: flutter, camera

I want to use the front camera in flutter.
Instead of shooting mode, I want to make the front camera without a shooting button appear in real time for only about a third of the page.
Do you have any reference material?

Comment: you can use camera plugin and make your button as your need.
https://pub.dev/packages/camera

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reference Material -

https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/plugins/picture-using-camera#complete-example

Here, `final cameras = await availableCameras();` return the list of available cameras, and motstly the second one (index no 1) is front camera.
To use front camera, just change `final firstCamera = cameras.first;` to `final firstCamera = cameras[1];`

```
CameraPreview(_controller)
```

change or bound it with sized box to determine how much you wanna use to preview the camera's output!